# Shopify - Redirect URL for an active page

Tags: shopify

when url contains returns I want to redirect to https://orakiyoga.returnscenter.com/
Shopify redirect tool does not work in this case because the original page is still active.
I guess I need the right code and add it to theme.liquid?

Can you help with the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help. I can't test it because I don't have access to your actual code, but you should be able to put this at the top of the main theme.liquid file and it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("returns") >= -1) {
        window.open("https://orakiyoga.returnscenter.com/","_self");
    }
</script>
```